# Is there an infinite group whose elements all have finite order?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is there an infinite (edit: but finitely generated) group G such that for all g in G, |g| is finite?

If so, how many such groups exist?

Comment: The direct sum of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb Z_2$. 

Comment: Edit to specify "infinite finitely generated group"?  Anyone?

Comment: Yes, Grigorchuk group is a finitely generated infinite 2-group. I.e, for each $g\in G$ there is an $n$ such that g^(2^n)=1.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, as per Ryan's comment you can just take an infinite direct sum of finite groups. However the more interesting problem is: are there (infinite) $\textit{finitely generated}$ groups with all elements of finite order?

The answer to this was open for a long time, but it is indeed yes. In fact this was known as Burnside's problem

The first examples were given by Golod & Shafarevich.

There is a lot of info on the wikipedia page

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_problem

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Nitpicky requests: will you edit to say you want your groups to be infinite cardinality, and remove the "alot"? (http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)

Comment: Done. In general, though, let's not worry about such picayune errors. I recommend a good dose of Language Log to those who worry alot about correct grammer and spelling. ;-) 

Comment: Heh, thanks.  I care a lot more about the precision in math than grammar on this forum, but I couldn't resist the addition; my genuine-linguist friends have as yet failed to convince me that prescriptivism is always bad.

Comment: Elizabeth, even so, there's a huge difference between a grammatical error and a typographical error.